# Create a mechanism to support a speaker in the upper part of an enclosure

Tags: cad, technical-drawing, plastic, product-support

I am working on an electronics enclosure.
There will be two parts, the main enclosure and the lid that gets screwed.

In the upper lid, I want to have a support for a circular mini speaker.
The speaker does not have surfaces to screw it, or to "grab it".

I opened up a case that is decades before. This is what they did in order to support a speaker in the upper part of the enclosure.

[image]

As you can see here, they have created a circular surface, surrounded by walls, to keep the speaker in, and they also have plastic bars, outside the aforementioned wall.
Then, they melted the plastic bars, in order to support the speaker.

I don't think this is a very valid way to create a support for a structure.
Is there a more "official" way to create a mechanism to securely support a speaker in the upper part of the case?

Comment: what do you mean by "official"?

Comment: Mechanism would imply something is moving. But yes this is one of the common easy ways of attaching things in mass production, along with casting inside object but with less logistical problems. Another is to use gluing or hot snot.

Comment: I meant a common way to do this in the inductry. BTW, what is a hot snot?

Answer (score 3):

That is a piezo-electric transducer. ("Speaker" usually means a device consisting of a device with a paper or plastic cone driven by a voice coil.)

Heat staking of the part is an excellent solution for mass production. It uses no parts and can be done automatically or manually. The most common alternative would be snap "barbed" latches or screws to hold the edges in position.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have a term `heat staking`. As for the screws, I don't want to get in that area. The `barbed latches` one I did not understand. But I am interested in the procedure in the picture, that you classified as heat staking. How exactly do I do this? Is there any reference online?

Comment: Use a soldering iron type instrument with a tip that you won't be using for soldering. See the bottom of page 8 of [this](https://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/S62.12/people/vernelle.noel/Plastic_Snap_fit_design.pdf) for an idea of snap mount. For a thin part (such as a PCB or your sounder) supports would be required to bring the component to the right height. (The snap needs to be long enough to flex without breaking.)

Comment: I saw the picture, however I cannot visualize how these four pillars would deform with a soldering iron. In my mind, it seems like they would break. Or they will melt, but not create a hinge to hold the speaker. Do you happen to know of any video of the process? Also, what do you mean with `supports would be required to bring the component to the right height`?

Comment: Read my comment again. The photo is of a snap fastener, not a heat stake post. You're not making a hinge, just something that will flex enough to allow the part in but not out. The snaps in the photo are designed to hold down something that's 10 mm thick. If you were holding a 1.2 mm PCB then you would need 8.8 mm supports to lift the PCB to the height of the snaps. This would allow air to circulate below the PCB.